# Could someone explain the logic for drawing a triangle using DDA scanlines given 3 vertices?

Tags: java, graphics

Say I have 3 vertices: (20, 20), (10, 60), (50, 60)

How would I draw a triangle?

I was thinking first you need to connect the vertices to get the edges of the triangle. This would be done by getting the slope? Then you find the leftmost vertex, and start incrementing up in y and setting pixels along the x until you hit the right edge?

Pseudocode would be extremely helpful, but I'm having trouble understanding the basic idea as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this. One of the simpler ways is called the half-space method, and involves drawing a bounding rectangle around the triangle, and then iterating through all of the pixels of the rectangle. If the pixel is inside the triangle, color the pixel.

Example:

```
//Initialize these however you want to
int x1;
int x2;
int x3;
int y1;
int y2;
int y3;

//Bounding rectangle
int minX = min(x1, x2, x3)
int maxX = max(x1, x2, x3)
int minY = min(y1, y2, y3)
int maxY = max(y1, y2, y3)

for(int x = minX; x <= maxX; x++)
{
    for(int y = minY; y <= maxY; y++)
    {
        //If point in triangle
        if((x1 - x2) * (y - y1) - (y1 - y2) * (x - x1) > 0 &&
           (x2 - x3) * (y - y2) - (y2 - y3) * (x - x2) > 0 &&
           (x3 - x1) * (y - y3) - (y3 - y1) * (x - x3) > 0)
        {
            //Color pixel
        }
    }
}
```

The min and max methods have to be implemented by you, and you can use whatever method you like for determining whether a point is in a triangle or not if you don't like the one shown above.